# Databricks checkpoint java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory:

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, databricks, aws-glue-data-catalog

I try to execute this writeStream

```
def _write_stream(data_frame, checkpoint_path, write_stream_path):
        data_frame.writeStream.format("delta") \
            .option("checkpointLocation", checkpoint_path) \
            .trigger(processingTime="1 second") \
            .option("mergeSchema", "true") \
            .outputMode("append") \
            .table(write_stream_path)
```

but I get this error

> at
> org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:428)
> at
> org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.parallelMap(ThreadUtils.scala:399)
> at
> com.databricks.sql.streaming.state.RocksDBFileManager.loadImmutableFilesFromDbfs(RocksDBFileManager.scala:433)
> at
> com.databricks.sql.streaming.state.RocksDBFileManager.loadCheckpointFromDbfs(RocksDBFileManager.scala:202)
> at
> com.databricks.sql.rocksdb.CloudRocksDB.$anonfun$open$5(CloudRocksDB.scala:437)
> at
> scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
> at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.timeTakenMs(Utils.scala:627)    at
> com.databricks.sql.rocksdb.CloudRocksDB.timeTakenMs(CloudRocksDB.scala:523)
> at
> com.databricks.sql.rocksdb.CloudRocksDB.$anonfun$open$2(CloudRocksDB.scala:435)
> at
> com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.$anonfun$recordOperation$1(UsageLogging.scala:369)
> at
> com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.executeThunkAndCaptureResultTags$1(UsageLogging.scala:457)
> at
> com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.$anonfun$recordOperationWithResultTags$4(UsageLogging.scala:477)
> at
> com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.$anonfun$withAttributionContext$1(UsageLogging.scala:240)
> at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:62)   at
> com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionContext(UsageLogging.scala:235)
> at
> com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionContext$(UsageLogging.scala:232)
> at
> com.databricks.spark.util.PublicDBLogging.withAttributionContext(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:20)
> at
> com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags(UsageLogging.scala:279)
> at
> com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags$(UsageLogging.scala:271)
> at
> com.databricks.spark.util.PublicDBLogging.withAttributionTags(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:20)
> at
> com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.recordOperationWithResultTags(UsageLogging.scala:452)
> at
> com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.recordOperationWithResultTags$(UsageLogging.scala:378)
> at
> com.databricks.spark.util.PublicDBLogging.recordOperationWithResultTags(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:20)
> at
> com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.recordOperation(UsageLogging.scala:369)
> at
> com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.recordOperation$(UsageLogging.scala:341)
> at
> com.databricks.spark.util.PublicDBLogging.recordOperation(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:20)
> at
> com.databricks.spark.util.PublicDBLogging.recordOperation0(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:57)
> at
> com.databricks.spark.util.DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.recordOperation(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:125)
> at
> com.databricks.spark.util.UsageLogger.recordOperation(UsageLogger.scala:70)
> at
> com.databricks.spark.util.UsageLogger.recordOperation$(UsageLogger.scala:57)
> at
> com.databricks.spark.util.DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.recordOperation(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:86)
> at
> com.databricks.spark.util.UsageLogging.recordOperation(UsageLogger.scala:402)
> at
> com.databricks.spark.util.UsageLogging.recordOperation$(UsageLogger.scala:381)
> at
> com.databricks.sql.rocksdb.CloudRocksDB.recordOperation(CloudRocksDB.scala:52)
> at
> com.databricks.sql.rocksdb.CloudRocksDB.recordRocksDBOperation(CloudRocksDB.scala:542)
> at
> com.databricks.sql.rocksdb.CloudRocksDB.$anonfun$open$1(CloudRocksDB.scala:427)
> at
> com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ProgressReporter$.withStatusCode(ProgressReporter.scala:377)
> at
> com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ProgressReporter$.withStatusCode(ProgressReporter.scala:363)
> at
> com.databricks.spark.util.SparkDatabricksProgressReporter$.withStatusCode(ProgressReporter.scala:34)
> at
> com.databricks.sql.rocksdb.CloudRocksDB.open(CloudRocksDB.scala:427)
> at
> com.databricks.sql.rocksdb.CloudRocksDB.(CloudRocksDB.scala:80)
> at
> com.databricks.sql.rocksdb.CloudRocksDB$.open(CloudRocksDB.scala:595)
> at
> com.databricks.sql.fileNotification.autoIngest.CloudFilesSource.(CloudFilesSource.scala:82)
> at
> com.databricks.sql.fileNotification.autoIngest.CloudFilesNotificationSource.(CloudFilesNotificationSource.scala:44)
> at
> com.databricks.sql.fileNotification.autoIngest.CloudFilesSourceProvider.createSource(CloudFilesSourceProvider.scala:172)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.createSource(DataSource.scala:326)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$1.$anonfun$applyOrElse$1(MicroBatchExecution.scala:100)
> at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.getOrElseUpdate(HashMap.scala:86)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(MicroBatchExecution.scala:97)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(MicroBatchExecution.scala:95)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$1(TreeNode.scala:484)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:86)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:484)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:262)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:258)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:460)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transform(TreeNode.scala:428)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.planQuery(MicroBatchExecution.scala:95)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.logicalPlan$lzycompute(MicroBatchExecution.scala:165)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.logicalPlan(MicroBatchExecution.scala:165)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.$anonfun$runStream$1(StreamExecution.scala:349)
> at
> scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:852)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runStream(StreamExecution.scala:341)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:268)
> Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory:
> s3://****/******/*******/checkpoint/sources/0/rocksdb/SSTs/******.sst
> at
> shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.s3GetFileStatus(S3AFileSystem.java:3254)
> at
> shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.innerGetFileStatus(S3AFileSystem.java:3137)
> at
> shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.getFileStatus(S3AFileSystem.java:3076)
> at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:337)    at
> org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:289)     at
> org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.copyToLocalFile(FileSystem.java:2034)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.copyToLocalFile(FileSystem.java:2003)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.copyToLocalFile(FileSystem.java:1979)
> at
> com.databricks.sql.streaming.state.RocksDBFileManager.$anonfun$loadImmutableFilesFromDbfs$6(RocksDBFileManager.scala:442)
> at
> com.databricks.sql.streaming.state.RocksDBFileManager.$anonfun$loadImmutableFilesFromDbfs$6$adapted(RocksDBFileManager.scala:433)
> at
> org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.$anonfun$parallelMap$2(ThreadUtils.scala:397)
> at scala.concurrent.Future$.$anonfun$apply$1(Future.scala:659)  at
> scala.util.Success.$anonfun$map$1(Try.scala:255)  at
> scala.util.Success.map(Try.scala:213)     at
> scala.concurrent.Future.$anonfun$map$1(Future.scala:292)  at
> scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.liftedTree1$1(Promise.scala:33)     at
> scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.$anonfun$transform$1(Promise.scala:33)
> at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:64)     at
> org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingRunnable.$anonfun$run$1(SparkThreadLocalForwardingThreadPoolExecutor.scala:104)
> at
> scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
> at
> org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingHelper.runWithCaptured(SparkThreadLocalForwardingThreadPoolExecutor.scala:68)
> at
> org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingHelper.runWithCaptured$(SparkThreadLocalForwardingThreadPoolExecutor.scala:54)
> at
> org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingRunnable.runWithCaptured(SparkThreadLocalForwardingThreadPoolExecutor.scala:101)
> at
> org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingRunnable.run(SparkThreadLocalForwardingThreadPoolExecutor.scala:104)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: If the checkpoint location is inside the data path and you did a vacuuming, it will corrupt it.
It is a good practice to place the checkpoint location outside the data path.

Answer (score 0):

Please check on checkpoint_path location is present or not . Error log clearly tells , path is not exists.

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory: s3:///**/*/checkpoint/sources/0/rocksdb/SSTs/.sst
```

Comment: I checked and it is there